# Replace a list value in yaml with yq

Tags: bash, yaml, yq, pcf

I have a Yaml file as below and would like to replace "cups-stage-service" with "cups-stage-blue-service".

In the YAML file 'cups-stage-service' is at index 0 but not necessarily at index 0. some times it may be below 'dyn-service'. I wanted to find and replace in any index.

I would also want to use regex like "cups-stage-service.*" to find and replace it as it also not necessarily be 'cups-stage-service' but something like 'cups-stage-service-full-name'.

```
---
applications:
  - name: cv-service
    buildpacks:
      - dotnet_core_buildpack_latest
    stack: cflinuxfs3
    instances: 8
    memory: 1G
    disk_quota: 1G
    log-rate-limit-per-second: 24KB
    health-check-type: http
    health-check-http-endpoint: /ping
    health-check-invocation-timeout: 5
    timeout: 180
    services:
      - cups-stage-service
      - dyn-service
    env:
      ENVIRONMENT: stage
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: stage
```

I tried using yq in combination with select(), test(), and a few others but nothing works.

I wanted to do it with yq only rather than sed/awk with which it's easily achievable.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You have to specify exactly what the string might look like: is "starts with `cups-stage-service`" precise enough to always identify the correct array element?

Comment: I have multiple yaml files like few are with the service full name `cups-stage-service-full-name` and a few are with the service's short name `cups-stage-service-shortname`. The common part across the services is the `cups-stage-service`.  irrespective of names, I want to insert `blue` exactly after the environment i.e., `cups-stage-blue-service-fullname` or `cups-stage-blue-service-shortname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `test` to get a boolean value from a RegEx test:

```bash
(.applications[].services[] | select(test("cups-stage-service.*"))) = "cups-stage-blue-service"
```

```yaml
---
applications:
  - name: cv-service
    buildpacks:
      - dotnet_core_buildpack_latest
    stack: cflinuxfs3
    instances: 8
    memory: 1G
    disk_quota: 1G
    log-rate-limit-per-second: 24KB
    health-check-type: http
    health-check-http-endpoint: /ping
    health-check-invocation-timeout: 5
    timeout: 180
    services:
      - cups-stage-blue-service
      - dyn-service
    env:
      ENVIRONMENT: stage
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: stage
```

Works with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), and [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq).

Comment: @VenuReddy That's not the query I gave you. Why did you change `.services[]` to `.services`? Why did you change `=` to `|=`? Why did you remove the outer parentheses around the part left of `=`? Also note that you have changed the regex from `.*` to `-*` which may not do what you want if you are confusing regex with globbing. With the latter, you cannot use `test`. Using mikefarah/yq, you would rather use it in comparisons like `==`.

Comment: I tested with the old YQ version unknowingly on a different box. I updated the version and it all works fine.

Thanks, @pmf ...

Also, how do we use a variable instead of passing '- cups-stage-blue-service' directly?

Comment: @VenuReddy Based on your previous error message, I suppose you are using mikefarah/yq. Then you can use `env` to access environment variables: `regex='cups-stage-service.*' subst='cups-stage-blue-service' yq '(.applications[].services[] | select(test(env(regex)))) = env(subst)'`.

Comment: Yes, I'm on mikefarah/yq & it works perfectly, Thanks a lot @pmf